# Tile layer not working in Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver, wms, tiles

I have several layers in my workspace, stored in postGIS. If I go to "preview layers", it will work OK, not tiled though.

I need it to be tiled for my app, so I have it activated in all my layers, and as such, every one of them is shown in "Cached layers", but if I try to preview them, it's just an empty canvas. If I do a GET petition from my app, it works but it's just empty.

I've got my suspicions but WMS service is OK as normal layers work.

Any idea?

Comment: what is in the log file when you make the request? what is the exact request  you make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as always I found the answer just after asking.

The problem was that my native SRS was different than the declared one, and in the layer config, I forgot to set it to "Reproject from native to declared" (sorry if this is not the accurate option, my geoserver is in spanish!) u__u'